# Hibernate failing to update object

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am using hibernate's EntityManager to save an object and then update the same. My code looks something like :

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "demoPU")
private EntityManager em;

E e = new E();
e.setDescription("Description");

e = em.merge(e);
em.flush();

e.setDescription("newDescription");
e = em.merge(e);
em.flush();
```

The Id of the class E is generated using @PrePersist.

The hibernate logs look something like:

```
Hibernate: insert into E (Description, ID) values (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into E (Description, ID) values (?, ?, ?)
```

So basically hibernate is trying to insert the same object twice with the same ID. This in turn gives the following exception:

```
org.hsqldb.HsqlException: integrity constraint violation: unique constraint or index violation; SYS_PK_10253 table: POLICY
```

Can someone let me know why is hibernate running an `insert` statement instead of `update` even though I am using entity managers `merge` to both save and update the object ? Also how can I actually update the object in this case ?

EDIT : Class E looks like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "E")
public class E {

    @Id
    @Column(name="ID",nullable = false)
    private String id;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "Description", nullable = false)
    private String Description;

    // Getters setters etc

    public String getId(){
        if(this.id == null ){
            this.setId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        }
        return id;
    }


    @PrePersist
    private void verifyPrimaryKeyAssigned(){
        getId();
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = super.hashCode();
        result = prime * result + ((getId() == null) ? 0 : getId().hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (!super.equals(obj))
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Policy other = (Policy) obj;
        if (getId() == null) {
            if (other.getId() != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!getId().equals(other.getId()))
            return false;

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the ddl specilly the key `SYS_PK_10253`

Comment: merge causes an onFlushDirty, (and you've messed with your entity, so it's dirty) it's correct that it's trying to insert it again

Comment: Shouldn't your first merge be a persist?

Comment: @Jens : It is not being logged, but I believe it is the unique constraints on the Id Column (annotated with @Id) of E.

Comment: That usually happens when you change the signature of your object . When you recover the object don't try to reinitiate it  , just pass it as it is .

Comment: @RobinJonsson If updating like this causes the entity to become dirty, can you let me know what is the correct way of going about this.

Comment: @M.Deinum : Ideally yes. But merge should not cause an issue.

Comment: @Kibadachi : I am not reinitializing the object. I am just modifying the existing one.

Comment: Do you have a proper `hashCode` and `equals` method? If that includes all fields it might trick hibernate into thinking it is a different object...

Comment: Can you please add them to your question (or maybe your `E` class). Also you mention `@PrePersist` but you are merging and not persisting, are you sure the id is generated and that you are not trying to insert a `null` value...

Comment: @M.Deinum : Added E. Since I am using the same object `e`, it's Id is set during the first `em.merge(e);`

Comment: Don't use `@PrePersist` to generate the id; you are misusing the lifecycle callbacks. Implement the custom id generator. Regarding your issue, did you see that the id is assigned on the first merge or you just expect it?

Comment: @DraganBozanovic : The id is assigned on the second insert and it is same  as the one in the first one.

Answer (score 0):

i think it would be clearer to use 'persist' instead of 'merge' if you want to persist an entity for the first time.

in your example there is no need to call 'merge' twice since you get back a managed entity from the first merge and you are altering the entity you got back from merge your changes will automatically be persisted when your transaction commits.